Multiple Instances of singleton when using BuildServiceProvider
I am trying to create a depenency injection pipeline service that runs as a Background service.  The idea is that I can create one to many of these services and pass in simple IOption config for some values that need to change in each step (loaded using the service key), i regiter them a keyed services so they do not overwite each other.
I also have a queue mananger that is created as a singleton that allow me to get producers/consumers base on queue config also passed in a IOptions config.
I pass in a different service key for each version of the pipeline that i want to create
A simple version of my code (cut down to just the basics is below)
public IServiceCollection AddPipelineService(this IServiceCollection services, 
IConfigurationManager configuration, string serviceKey)
{
 // Get Config for the steps based on the sevice key
 var StepOptions = Options.Create(
     configuration
     .GetSection($"{serviceKey}:{StepOptions.StepOptionsName}")
     .Get<MessageFactoryOptions>());

 // Build a list of steps and reister a service 
 services.AddKeyedSingleton<IStep, Step1>(serviceKey, (p,o) => new Step1(p.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ConfirmResponseMessageFactory>>(), stepOptions);
 services.AddKeyedSingleton<IStep, Step2>(serviceKey, (p, o) => new Step2(p.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ConfirmResponseMessageFactory>>(), stepOptions);
 services.AddKeyedSingleton<IStep, Step3>(serviceKey, (p, o) => new Step3(p.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ConfirmResponseMessageFactory>>(), stepOptions);

 // Create the service provider
 var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);

 // Add the steps to a set collection
 IEnumerable<IStep> steps = provider.GetKeyedServices<IMessageProcessItem>(serviceKey);
 services.AddKeyedSingleton<IStepCollection, StepCollection>(serviceKey, (p, o) => new StepCollection(steps));

 // Create the queue options based on the service key
 var queueOptions = Options.Create(
     configuration
     .GetSection($"{serviceKey}:{QueueOptions.QueueOptionsName}")
     .Get<MessageFactoryOptions>());

 // NOTE 
 //  IQueueManager registered earlier as a singleton (i only want to onpen a siingle connection and reuse for creation of consumers and producers)
 //  PipelineBackgroundService is a BackgroundService

 services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, PipelineBackgroundService>(
     p => new PipelineBackgroundService(
         p.GetRequiredService<ILogger<PipelineBackgroundService>>(),
         p.GetRequiredService<IQueueManager>(),
         p.GetRequiredKeyedService<IStepCollection>(serviceKey),
         queueOptions);

 return services;
}

All this works but i end up with multiple versions of queue manager becuase i call BuildServiceProvider which i believe creates a new container.  But i have read i should avoid using BuildServiceProvider
Is there a way I can do this without this side affectand with out using BuildServiceProvider.
Thanks,
Nick

Why you can't just dont create it and make everything in delegates? Seems pretty obvious that you can just get all steps without provider, just in next registration of IStepCollection

You are writing that you have multiple instances of IQueueManager. But where is it created? It’s not in the provided code.

@eocron - thanks, if you could expand on that a bit in an answer, then I will put this as my accepted answer

@MykhailoSvyrydovych -  queue manager is registered as a singleton but the code above produced a new instance each time I called the method due to using BuildServiceProvider

Based on @eocron comment I was able to create the desired result with ot the need to call BuildServiceProvider, I just changed the code to use the provider in the registing of the StepCollection like so:
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IStepCollection, StepCollection>(serviceKey, 
    (p, o) => new StepCollection(p.GetKeyedServices<IMessageProcessItem>(serviceKey)));

and now there is only a single instance of the QueueManager created
